# Python program not accepting decimal raw input

Tags: python, floating-point, raw-input

I am working on small python payroll  project where you enter employee name, wage, and hours worked.  When I enter decimals for the wage input, I am getting "invalid entry" because of my exception handling.  Why are decimals being returned as invalid?  Also, how can I loop this program so that it keeps the same 3 questions until the user types "Done"?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

```
import cPickle

def getName():
    strName="dummy"
    lstNames=[]
    strName=raw_input("Enter employee's Name: ")
    lstNames.append(strName.title() + " \n")


def getWage():
    lstWage=[]
    strNum="0"
    blnDone=False
    while blnDone==False: #loop to stay in program until valid data is entered
        try:
            intWage=int(raw_input("Enter employee's wage: "))
            if intWage >= 6.0 and intWage <=20.0:
                lstWage.append(float(strNum)) #convert to float
                blnDone=True
            else:
                print "Wage must be between $6.00 and $20.00"
        except(ValueError): #if you have Value Error exception.  Explicit on error type
            print "Invalid entry"


def getHours():
    lstHours=[]
    blnDone=False
    while blnDone==False: #loop to stay in program until valid data is entered
        try:
            intHrs=int(raw_input("Enter number of hours worked: "))
            if intHrs >= 1.0 and intHrs <=60.0:
                blnDone=True
            else:
                print "Hours worked must be 1 through 60."
        except(ValueError): #if you have Value Error exception.  Explicit on error type
            print "Invalid entry"

def getDone():
    strDone=""
    blnDone=False
    while blnDone==False:
        try:
            srtDone=raw_input("Type \"DONE\" if you are finished entering names, otherwise press enter: ")
            if strDone.lower()=="done":
                blnDone=True
            else:
                print "Type another empolyee name"
        except(ValueError): #if you have Value Error exception.  Explicit on error type
            print "Invalid entry"


##### Mainline ########

strUserName=getName()
strWage=getWage()
strHours=getHours()
srtDone1=getDone()
```

Comment: Ugh, hungarian notation is disgusting. Especially when used incorrectly (you are compating `intWage` with a float). You might want to have a look at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ regarding python code style.

Comment: While not actually what the question was about, you seem to have a strange use of the input. You read in a wage with `raw_input`, check for the range it occurs in, and then ignore it in favor of `strNum`, which is always zero.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Hungarian notation is brilliant! Just not like this! millisecondTime and microsecondTime, or feetDistance and meterDistance would have saved NASA quite a few bucks...

Comment: @brice: Pretty much everyone who talks about HN means the one which includes the data type, not the units ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the wage is an integer, which by definition does not have a decimal place. Try this:

```
intWage=float(raw_input("Enter employee's wage: "))
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much for your help.  After staring at this program for hours, the little obvious things slipped by.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the core of it:

```
>>> int("4.3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.3'
```

You can't convert a string to an integer if it's not an integer. So when you do `intWage=int(raw_input("Enter employee's wage: "))` it throws the `ValueError`. Perhaps you should convert it directly to `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're converting the input to `int`:

```
intWage=int(raw_input("Enter employee's wage: "))
```

Comment: It's always something so obvious.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
intWage=int(float(raw_input("Enter employee's wage: ")))
```

This will accept a decimal number as input.

Answer (score 0):

## Error w/ Floats

As others said before, you are assuming the input will be a float. Either use `float()` or `eval()`instead of `int()`:

```
intWage = float(raw_input("Enter employee's wage: "))
```

Or use `input()` instead of `int(raw_input())`:

```
intWage = input("Enter employee's wage:")
```

Both will accomplish the same thing. Oh, and change `intWage` to `floatWage` atleast, or even better, don't use Hungarian Notation.

## The Code

As for your code, I did a couple of things:

- Used `break` and/or `return` to terminate loops instead of keeping track of booleans (that's the whole purpose of the `break` and `continue` statements)
- Changed `intWage` to `floatWage`
- Rewrote number comparisons in a more concise way (`x <= y and x >= z` can be written as `z >= x >= y`)
- Added return statements. I don't get why you didn't put them yourself, unless you wanted to assign `None` to `strUserName`, `strWage` and `strHours`)
- Added a loop as you requested when asking for an employee's details.
- Modified `getDone()` to work w/ the loop.

`import cPickle`

```
def getName():
    strName = "dummy"
    lstNames = []
    strName = raw_input("Enter employee's Name: ")
    lstNames.append(strName.title() + " \n")
    return strName

def getWage():
    lstWage = []
    strNum = "0"
    while True:                                                #Loop to stay in program until valid data is entered
        try:
            floatWage = float(raw_input("Enter employee's wage: "))
            if 6.0 <= floatWage <= 20.0:
                lstWage.append(floatWage)
                return floatWage
            else:
                print "Wage must be between $6.00 and $20.00"
        except ValueError:                                     #Catches ValueErrors from conversion to float
            print "Invalid entry"

def getHours():
    lstHours = []
    while True:                                                #loop to stay in program until valid data is entered
        try:
            intHrs=int(raw_input("Enter number of hours worked: "))
            if 1.0 <= intHrs <= 60.0:
                return intHrs
            else:
                print "Hours worked must be 1 through 60."
        except ValueError:                                     #Catches ValueErrors from conversion to int
            print "Invalid entry"

def getDone():
    strDone = ""
    while True:
        srtDone = raw_input('Type "DONE" if you are finished entering names, otherwise press enter: ')
        if strDone.strip().lower() == "done":
            return True
        else:
            print "Type another empolyee name"

while not getDone():
    strUserName = getName()
    strWage = getWage()
    strHours = getHours()
```

## An Example of `break` and `continue`

The `break` statements inside a loop (`for` and `while`) terminate the loop and skip all 'else' clauses (if there are any).

The`continue` statements skips the rest of the code in the loop and the *continues* the loop as if nothing happened.

The `else` clause in a `for...else` construct, executes its code block when the loop exhausted all the items and exited normally, i.e., when it's not terminated by `break` or something.

```
for no in range(2, 10):
    for factor in range(2, no):
        if no % factor == 0:
            if factor == 2:
                print "%d is even" % no
                continue  
                # we want to skip the rest of the code in this for loop for now
                # as we've already done the printing
            print "%d = %d * %d" % (no, factor, n/x)
            break 
           # We've asserted that the no. isn't prime, 
           # we don't need to test the other factors
    else:
        # if 'break' wasn't called
        # i.e., if the loop fell through w/o finding any factor
        print no, 'is a prime number'
```

Comment: Just curious if you could give me an example?  My python instructor told the class that he is against using "break" therefore never really showed us how to use it.  "Continue" was never even brought up.

Comment: @user1298258 `break` terminates the loop early and `continue` skips the rest of the code in the loop and the _continues_ the loop as if nothing happened (Sorry if it's a bit convoluted).

Comment: There is no reason not to use `break`, in fact it's encouraged as it's more concise than using a boolean with all the boilerplate associated w/ it. I don't see any reason for your instructor to hate it.

Comment: `break` also skips any else clauses in a `for...else` construct.